# Create a table of contents with links in all text and different colours for sections and page number using pdflatex

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, links

**Introduction**

I would like to create a table of contents with links in all *text* **and** *page number* but with different colours for the text and page numbers and it should **compile with pdflatex**.

**Work done**

I have the (minimal) working code below.

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, openany, oneside]{book}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[bookmarks,hypertexnames=false,debug,linktocpage=true,hidelinks]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linktoc=all,
    linkcolor={blue},
    citecolor={blue},
    urlcolor={blue}
}



\begin{document}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\color{red}\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}[]
\sectionfont{\color{red}}
\subsectionfont{\color{red}}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{A Section}
Text goes here.
\section{Another Section}
Text goes here.
\subsection{A Sub Section}
Text goes here.
\section{One more section Section}
Text goes here.

\chapter{Chapter One}
Text goes here.
\section{A Section}
Text goes here.
\section{Another Section}
Text goes here.

\end{document}
```

This gives the following output for the table of contents:

[image]

It also gives the following output for a chapter

[image]

**Desired outcome**

I would like to have a *table of contents* where *all text* (chapter headings, section headings, subsection headings, page number etc.) *are hyperlinks* to the relevant section but have *customized colours* for the section headings, subsection headings and page numbers in the table of contents.

It should also *compile with pdflatex* (not xelatex, lualatex etc.).

Here is a summary of the desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I patch the `\contentsline` command to locally change the link color used in title part of toc entry (compared to the page number part), per toc type.

In the following example,

- the title part of chapter toc entry is changed to `red` by `\def\toccolor@chapter{red}`, and
- the title part of section and subsection toc entries are changed to `black` by `\def\toccolor@section{black}` and `\def\toccolor@subsection{black}`, respectively.

To apply this for other types of toc entries,

1. find the corresponding auxiliary file. For example, `\listoftables` uses aux file `.lot`.
2. find the type of toc entry this list uses. For example, in `.lot` file you can see lines like `\contentsline {table}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces Title}}{1}%`, then `table` (the first argument of `\contentsline`) is the type name.
3. provide corresponding `\toccolor@<type>` command. In the previous example, with `\def\toccolor@table{<color>}`, the color of title part of toc entries `table` will typeset in `<color>`.

```tex
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, openany, oneside]{book}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage[bookmarks,hypertexnames=false,debug,linktocpage=true,hidelinks]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linktoc=all,
    linkcolor={blue},
    citecolor={blue},
    urlcolor={blue}
}


\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\color{red}\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
  {\thechapter}{1em}
  {}[]
\sectionfont{\color{red}}
\subsectionfont{\color{red}}


\makeatletter
% redefine \contentsline, locally change linkcolor
\IfPackageAtLeastTF{hyperref}{2022-11-13}{\@tempswatrue}{\@tempswafalse}
\if@tempswa
  % see https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/commit/7bf9ab4c99c434c30d0d00771326ae3d487fb092
  \xpatchcmd\contentsline
    {%
      \csname l@#1\endcsname{%
        \Hy@toclinkstart{#2}\Hy@toclinkend
      }{%
        \Hy@toclinkstart{#3}\Hy@toclinkend
      }%
    }
    {%
      \csname l@#1\endcsname{%
        \begingroup
          \def\@linkcolor{black}%
          \Hy@toclinkstart{#2}\Hy@toclinkend
        \endgroup
      }{%
        \Hy@toclinkstart{#3}\Hy@toclinkend
      }%
    }
    {}{\PatchFailedII}
\else
  \xpatchcmd\contentsline
    {%
      \csname l@#1\endcsname{%
        \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#2}\hyper@linkend
      }{%
        \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#3}\hyper@linkend
      }%
    }
    {%
      \csname l@#1\endcsname{%
        \begingroup
          \Hy@toccolor{#1}%
          \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#2}\hyper@linkend
        \endgroup
      }{%
        \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#3}\hyper@linkend
      }%
    }
    {}{\PatchFailedI}
\fi

% choose toc linkcolor, #1 is first arg of \contetnsline, 
% eg "chapter", "section"
\def\Hy@toccolor#1{%
  \ifcsname toccolor@#1\endcsname
    \edef\@linkcolor{\csname toccolor@#1\endcsname}%
  \fi
}

\def\toccolor@chapter{red}
\def\toccolor@section{black}
\def\toccolor@subsection{black}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{A Section}
Text goes here.
\section{Another Section}
Text goes here.
\subsection{A Sub Section}
Text goes here.
\section{One more section Section}
Text goes here.

\chapter{Chapter One}
Text goes here.
\section{A Section}
Text goes here.
\section{Another Section}
Text goes here.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is is possible to generalize this so that the text appears black for `\listoftables`, `\listoffigures` etc.?

Comment: @NM_ You can add `\def\toccolor@table{black}` and `\def\toccolor@figure{black}`.

Comment: thank you. This works for figures and tables, however subfigures in the list of figures still appear in the link colour. I also have some algorithms created using `algorithm2e` and the text for the algorithms appears in the link colour. Is it possible to fix this too? Thank you.

Comment: @NM_ I've added a general guide. See my updated answer.

Comment: great thank you! I will try to use it to figure out the remaining parts. thank you so much!

Comment: I tried the generalization and it worked for algorithms but not for subfigure. For algorithm, the `.loa` file has a line `\contentsline {algocf}{\numberline {4.1}{\ignorespaces $K-$Fold Cross-Validation\relax }}{91}{algocf.380}%` so `\def\toccolor@algocf{black}` worked. In the `.lof` file, there are lines such as `\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline {5.1a}{\ignorespaces Cross-validation plot.\relax }}{103}{figure.caption.417}%`, however `\def\toccolor@subfigure{black}` did not work and the links for subfigures still appear in the link colour. Any suggestions?

Comment: @NM_ There are multiple subcaption packages, can you provide an example generating caption of subfigure in `\listoffigures`? Either editing your existing question or posting a new one is acceptable.

Comment: I've tested with `subcaption` pacakge, it works.